# Button positioning according to wrong View

Tags: javascript, react-native

So all the components I am using were created by me excepting TextInput. In another Navigator route i used the all the components excepting TextInput and they worked as intended. But in this case, some how my Buttom positioning follows Card position and not the outer View

// GoalForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Button, Card } from '../components';
import { TextInput } from '@shoutem/ui';

export default class GoalList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    styles = {
        nameGoalContainer: {
            flexDirection: 'row'
        },
        center: {
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center'
        },
        rightLabels: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: 17
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
                <Header text="New Goal" color='#3f51b5' />
                <Card>
                    <View style={this.styles.nameGoalContainer}>
                        <View style={ [this.styles.center, { marginRight: 15 }] }>
                            <Text style={this.styles.rightLabels}>Title</Text>
                        </View>
                        <TextInput
                            maxLength={30}
                            placeholder="Buy a new graphics card"
                            style={{ flex: 3, textAlign: 'center' }}
                        />
                    </View>
                </Card>
                <Button
                    text="+"
                    onPress={ () => { console.log('Hello') } }
                    size='50'
                    fontSize='25'
                    color='#FFD600'
                    fontColor='white'
                    style= {{
                        bottom: 20,
                        right: 20
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

// Card.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';

class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    generateComponent() {
        const { cardStyleAndroid } = this.styles;
        const { style } = this.props;

        switch (Platform.OS) {
            case 'android':
                return (
                    <View style={[ cardStyleAndroid, style ]}>
                        { this.props.children }
                    </View>
                );
            case 'ios':
                return 0;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                { this.generateComponent() }
            </View>
        );
    }

    styles = {
        cardStyleAndroid: {
            elevation: 2,
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            marginHorizontal: 10,
            marginVertical: 7
        }
    }
}

Card.propTypes = {
    platform: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    style: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Card;
```

// Button.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Platform } from 'react-native';

class Button extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    generateComponent() {
        const { cardStyleAndroid } = this.styles;
        const { style } = this.props;

        switch (Platform.OS) {
            case 'android':
                return (
                    <View style={[ cardStyleAndroid, style ]}>
                        { this.props.children }
                    </View>
                );
            case 'ios':
                return 0;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                { this.generateComponent() }
            </View>
        );
    }

    styles = {
        cardStyleAndroid: {
            elevation: 2,
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            marginHorizontal: 10,
            marginVertical: 7
        }
    }
}

Button.propTypes = {
    platform: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    style: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    children: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default Button;
```

// Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Platform } from 'react-native';

const generateShadow = () => {
    switch(Platform.OS) {
        case 'android':
            return { elevation: 5 };
        case 'ios':
            return 0;
    }
}

const Header = (props) => {
    const { textStyle, viewStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <View style={ [ viewStyle, { backgroundColor: props.color }, generateShadow() ] }>
            <Text style={textStyle}>{ props.text }</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

Header.propTypes = {
    color: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    text: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const styles = {
    textStyle: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20
    },
    viewStyle: {
        paddingLeft: 20,
        height: 55,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'space-around'
    }
};

export default Header;
```

Can anyone spot what I am missing here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I needed to wrap my card component in a View with flex:1